# Getting System.Data.DataRowView while getting value from ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to get data from database according to the item selected in the `ComboBox` but when I try to access the selected `ComboBox` item it gives me "System.Data.DataRowView" [...?]

I did the same thing with a simple select query in another function and that works fine but I don't know why it doesn't work in this query:

```
_dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT lt.Name FROM Leader as lt LEFT JOIN Material as mt ON lt.Student_id=mt.lead_id where lt.Name=" + "'" + cmbLeader.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
```

Can anybody tell me what might be the problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`SelectedItem` is the data object that is bound to the `ComboBox`'s data source, which in this case is `DataRowView`.

You need to cast `SelectedItem` to `DataRowView`, then retrieve the appropriate value from it.

You can do this as follows:

```
DataRowView oDataRowView = cmbLeader.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
string sValue = "";

if (oDataRowView != null) {
   sValue = oDataRowView.Row["YourFieldName"] as string;
}
```

then replace (in your CommandText):

```
cmbLeader.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

with:

```
sValue
```

This will gracefully handle the case where DataRowView is null.

`YourFieldName` in the above code should be the name of the field in the data source that contains the Name value. If you have set this field name in the combobox's `DisplayMember` or `ValueMember` properties, then you can just use this property instead in order to save yourself some heartache down the road when this field changes or when you want to reuse this code elsewhere:

```
   sValue = oDataRowView.Row[cmbLeader.DisplayMember] as string;
```

Alternatively, you can use `cmbLeader.SelectedValue`.

Comment: i tried using SelectedValue still i get System.Data.DataRowView , how can i cast from SelectedItem to DataRowView

Comment: thanx i found the way to cast SelectedItem to DataRowView String str = ((DataRowView)cmbLeader.SelectedItem)["Name"].ToString();

Comment: @jarus: updated the answer with details on casting to DataRowView.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind to an ADO `DataTable` you are really binding to an ADO `DataView` (which is a collection of DataRowViews). This means that the `SelectedItem` will always be a `DataRowView`.

To get the associated DataRow you can call

```
DataRow row = ((DataRowView)SelectedItem).Row
```

Answer (score 1):

This for DropDownList. Many Developer want to get the Data Member value from dropdown below function will help to get the value in easy way... if any Suggestion Comment Below!

```
 public string RadDropDownSelectValue(RadDropDownList radDropDownList)
    {
        string str = "";
        foreach (RadListDataItem item in radDropDownList.SelectedItems)
        {
            DataRowView dv = (DataRowView)item.Value;
            str = dv.Row[0].ToString();
        }
        return str;
    }
```