# Error: DropdownList Returning 'System.Data.DataRowView' as Text Value of the Item Selected

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu, datagridview

I have a Dropdown list in which I have all the banks names. I want to display the credit limit in a Data Grid View. But the Dropdown list is returning 'System.Data.DataRowView' as value of Selected Item.

Here is the code:

```
private void cbxBank_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = cbxBank.SelectedIndex;
    string bank = cbxBank.Text;
    if (i != -1)
    {
        // this Function Returns the Table of CreditLimit According to Bank Name
        DataTable CreditLimit = AM.ReturnAvailableCreditLimit(bank);

        //this function just displays the table in Datat Grid View
        DataGridViewDisplayDetails(CreditLimit);
    }
}
```

Code to Add Data in DropdownList

```
        Bank = DbRdRw.SqlDbRead("Select BankName from BankMaster", "BankMaster");
        cbxBank.DataSource = Bank;
        cbxBank.ValueMember = "BankName";
        cbxBank.DisplayMember = "BankName";
        //ends
```

Comment: I missed that the question is for Winform, actually `dropdownlist` is usually used with ASP.Net. However I have modified the my answer

Comment: In order to be able to get the value from SelectedItem you need to cast it - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8372479/43846 for how to do it

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify

For WinForm You need to specify the DataSource after defining the properties like:

```
Bank = DbRdRw.SqlDbRead("Select BankName from BankMaster", "BankMaster");
cbxBank.ValueMember = "BankName";
cbxBank.DisplayMember = "BankName";
cbxBank.DataSource = Bank; //here
```

For ASP.Net

```
cbxBank.DataSource = ....;//specify your datasource
cbxBank.DataValueField = "BankID";
cbxBank.DataTextField = "BankName";
cbxBank.DataBind();
```

Comment: i Edited the Question, Added the DataLoading into Dropdownlist Code

Comment: @Shivam, I missed that the question is for Winform, actually dropdownlist is usually used with ASP.Net. However I have modified the my answer

Comment: It still Shows all the Values in the Combo box as System.Data.DataRowView

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

- Override the .ToString() method of your object, displaying what you need
- Use the DisplayMemberPath(or equivalent) property of your dropdown list, displayiong the required property