# Not able to get selected row values from DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have written below to get value from selected row specific cell value. But it is not working. I have tried a lot, although same code is working in my projects other pages. Below is code, here is stack trace:

[image]

```
private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
      DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
      DataRowView rowSelected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
      label16.Content = Convert.ToString(rowSelected["quantity"]);
}
```

Comment: doesn't look like `DataRowView` object to me. more like anonymous type object

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372464/getting-system-data-datarowview-while-getting-value-from-combobox

Comment: I have been trying a lot, but all is going in vain. Although same lines of code are working in another file in same exact way.

Comment: it is not a *same exact way*, if it doesn't work. there must be a difference

Comment: I basically want that when datagrid row clicked its specific cell value should be displayed in label. Such as i have done in my code.

Comment: Image of stack trace is attached, do you have any guess what is problem. It gives me ERROR that Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: SelectedItem IS NOT a DataRowView object

Comment: Then what should i do is there any solution, i am trying since last 2 days.

Comment: FYI, the screenshot isn't of the stack trace but of the local variables.

Comment: Any idea how could i solve the problem ??

Comment: Please Upvote my Question, As stack overflow has stopped me to ask question just because of negative reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gd.SelectedItem` isn't a DataRowView, because after type cast `rowSelected` is `null`. Most likely it is anonymous type object (e.g. in case if ItemsSource is set from Entity Framework query results)

unless you change ItemsSource type to DataView, I can recommend 2 options:

use `dynamic` type:

```
private void dg_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
    dynamic rowSelected = gd.SelectedItem;
    label16.Content = rowSelected.quantity;
}
```

use Binding:

```
private void dg_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;

    BindingOperations.SetBinding(label16, Label.ContentProperty, new Binding("quantity") { Source = gd.SelectedItem });
}
```

Comment: A little question is that i think this code will not work with button_onclick event

Comment: in Button.Click event handler , `sender` will be Button. you can access label by name (`label16`), so give `DataGrid` a name (`<DataGrid Name="someDataGrid"/>`) and you will be able to take `someDataGrid.SelectedItem` in any place in code-behind

Comment: @JahanzaibNiazi, +3 isn't a negative reputation. It is not ethical to ask for upvotes. Keep in mind that Q and A get upvotes for their quality and usefulness, and Q which don't show research effort get downvoted